# multiple a bigint column and a decimal column in a table cell

Tags: sql, service, reporting

I have a field of bigint and a field of decimal in data base and i would like to multiple those fields in a tablecell in reportingservices.

My code is like this:

```
(Fields!dpr_unitprice.Value) * (Fields!dpr_PurchasedQuntity.Value)
```

but the result is not correct.

How can i get the correct result?

Comment: In *what way* is the result not correct? Do we have to guess every possible combination of incorrect behaviours and describe possible reasons for them occurring, in the hope that we find the right combination before the universe disappears? Only you're currently able to see the results, and should hopefully be able to describe the *input data*, the *desired* results, and the *actual* results.

Comment: What result are you expecting and what result are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

It might be that your DB engine is returning a bigint.

Cast the bigint value as a decimal before multiplying the two.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast both fields to the unit you want to work with, so if you want to work with decimal then:

```
cdec((Fields!dpr_unitprice.Value)) * (Fields!dpr_PurchasedQuntity.Value)
```